# Fiiling an image with color in android

Tags: android

how to fill an image with a color in android? Like the image given below

[image]

Comment: Lots of options but how are you drawing the image in the first place?

Comment: Use transparent image and colored background

Comment: its an icon for the home page of my app... when clicks that icon the color should be change to red.. is there any way?

Comment: set tint color property in xml

Comment: youcan use color filter for it

Comment: ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(resIdOfImageToFilter);
iv.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

Comment: #anonymous when i use that method the the whole color of image view becomes red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set color to the icon by using the below code

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_imageview);
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: use `backgroundTint` property in xml file of `ImageView`

Option 2:

```
ImageView imageView = ...;
Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
ColorFilter colorFilter = ColorFilterGenerator.from(drawable).to(Color.RED);
imageView.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
```

Comment: For this to work, first of all, image should be transparent png file and only non-transparent part can be colored using `backgroundTint` property

Comment: tint won't work for the given example image. tint will change the color of the borders here.

Comment: You have to make image as per requirement.
Please see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Since,Android Drawable Tinting is supported in Android 5.0+ (API 21+) only. (not 100% sure ). 
u can provide two different images in drawable folder and set it problematically when user clicks on it which will work in every android version.

```
public boolean enable = false;

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(enable)
{
 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_home_enable);
}
else
{
 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_home_disable);
}
            }
        });
```

Comment: is this the only way?